# Test linking is correct for C++ static library using CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have a CMake project that builds static libraries, and they will be linked into several other C++ projects to increase code reuse.

The project does not contain any testing yet, and I want to start adding it in and increase test code coverage as quickly as possible. This will involve quite a bit of work since the code is not very modular, and could take months to do before it is at a level that I consider acceptable.

One quick win I believe will improve testing is to check that these static libraries link correctly to third party libraries they are using. 
To do this I use CMake to link these static libraries into a test executable.

```
# Creating static library
# -------
add_library(StaticLib STATIC
    ${STATICLIB_SRC}
    ${STATICLIB_HEADERS}
)

target_link_libraries(StaticLib ${THIRD_PARTY_LIBRARIES})

target_include_directories(StaticLib 
PUBLIC 
${THIRD_PARTY_INCLUDES})
# -------

# Creating test executable, test using Boost
# -------
#Add compile target
add_executable(LibTest test.cpp)

# Add include directories
target_include_directories(LibTest 
    PRIVATE
    ${BOOST_INCLUDES} 
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:StaticLib,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
)

# Link to dependencies
target_link_libraries(LibTest
${BOOST_LIBS}
StaticLib
)
# -------
```

However, I have noticed that just linking it does not check for all missing symbols in the static libraries. It will only check for missing symbols in object files the test needs to link to.

For example, this test.cpp will give a link time error if the third party library is not linked correctly, because Foo cannot be instantiated:

```
// This is test.cpp
// The below will cause a link time error, if third party libraries are not linked correctly 
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(FooTest)
{
    Foo f = Foo();  // Defined in StaticLib and uses third party libraries
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE( "passed" );
}
```

However, this one will not generate an error:

```
// This is test.cpp
// The below will *not* cause a link time error, if third party libraries are not linked correctly 
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(FooTest)
{
    // No Foo being instantiated 
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE( "passed" );
}
```

**Is there any way to check that symbols exist for all object files in a static library, without having to write test code that will cover them?**

Comment: If you are using Linux, you could dump the symbols and check that they are all present.

Comment: What actually makes you doubt these symbols won't be present?

Comment: To complete answer of Matthieu Brucher under linux `nm --defined-only pathname_of_the_lib` returns the defined symbols and where they are (_nm_ not only works on static libs), obviously after you can pipe with a _grep_ etc

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ the third party libraries have been updated to newer versions, perhaps with breaking changes. I am also unsure whether some code is not just linking to libraries only present on a particular developers machine

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher thanks, I'm mostly using Linux so that will be useful for debug purposes for sure! However what I'm really looking for is automatically throwing an error for all missing symbols during a build using CMake, regardless of whether they're linked into a test executable

Comment: You can't. The only way to check that you have all symbols is to link an executable that asks for all of the symbols.

Comment: I see, I guess there's no other way around this other than increasing code coverage through my tests. It's comforting to know I'm not missing a trick somewhere!